How can I properly implement a ripple effect with a gradient background in a CardView in Android?
I’m trying to create a CardView in my Android app that has a gradient background and also includes a ripple effect when clicked. I’ve already defined a gradient drawable and set it as the background for the CardView, but I’m not sure how to add a ripple effect on top of this gradient.
Gradient Drawable (gradient_background.xml):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/gradient_start"
                android:endColor="@color/gradient_end"
                android:angle="45"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

CardView Layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_12sdp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/_12sdp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chapter_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/oswald_bold"
            android:text="Chapter Name"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18ssp"
            android:textShadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
            android:textShadowRadius="@dimen/_2sdp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chapter_completed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/oswald_medium"
            android:text="Completed"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


I want to add a ripple effect that overlays the gradient background so that the ripple effect is visible when the CardView is clicked. How can I properly combine these two elements?
I tried setting the ripple drawable directly as the background of the CardView, but it does not seem to overlay the gradient correctly.
